# Getting 'This operation is forbidden on unbound objects' when trying to monitor an Azure Batch task

Tags: azure-batch

I want to execute a simple task in Azure Batch, to wait until it completes and to get the result:

```cs
using (var client = _CreateBatchClient())
{
    var monitor = client.Utilities.CreateTaskStateMonitor();

    var task = new CloudTask(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "echo hello world");
    await client.JobOperations.AddTaskAsync("Test", task);
    await monitor.WhenAll(new List<CloudTask> { task }, TaskState.Completed, _timeout);

    var result = task.ExecutionInformation.Result;
}
```

And the `WhenAsync` line throws `System.InvalidOperationException: 'This operation is forbidden on unbound objects.'`

The message is quite obscure whereas I am not far from the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-parallel-dotnet#monitor-tasks). What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not obvious from this code yet actually Azure Batch does not know here how to identify the task. The job contains tasks but a task has no reference to a job it runs on. And the task Id does not globally identify the task as well, it only needs to be unique within a job.

This is probably the meaning of "unbound objects" here. The monitor just does not understand what to watch. Actually, if the `WhenAsync` line is commented, the next one throws a similar `InvalidOperationException: 'The property ExecutionInformation cannot be read while the object is in the Unbound state.'`

So the right way is to reference the task via the job:

```cs
using (var client = _CreateBatchClient())
{
    var monitor = client.Utilities.CreateTaskStateMonitor();

    var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var taskToAdd = new CloudTask(id, "echo hello world");
    await client.JobOperations.AddTaskAsync("Test", taskToAdd);

    var taskToTrack = await client.JobOperations.GetTaskAsync("Test", id);
    await monitor.WhenAll(new List<CloudTask> { taskToTrack }, TaskState.Completed, _timeout);
}
```

Compare:

[image: task to add]
[image: task to track]

And to get the result information, one needs to "find" the task in the job again, or it will be null.